# Jquery logic for open hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to develop a script that highlights text when a business is open. The hours are  8:30-12:30, 1:30-5:00.  I tried just highlighting based on day and that worked fine, but when I tried the hours my logic messes up. can anyone suggest a better way of doing this or lead me in the right direction. I am trying to see if there is a shorter statement to do this.

```
if(day==2 && ((hour >= 8 && min >= 30) ||(hour <= 13 && min <= 30))){
    $("#Tuesday").attr('id','open-hour')
}
```

Comment: Why are you resetting the "id" of the target element, instead of a class?

Comment: The id is just so I can find the element and then make the element bold

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using momentjs (http://momentjs.com/docs/)? It might be useful to check if the current time is within the range of working hours (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/min/)?

Answer (score 0):

This will pretty much always return true:

```
if(day==2 && ((hour >= 8 && min >= 30) ||(hour <= 13 && min <= 30))){
    $("#Tuesday").attr('id','open-hour')
}
```

This is because the hour will always be greater than 8 OR less than 13.  If the hour is 14, it's still greater than 8.

You should split that statement into 2 pieces.

Comment: What do you mean split it into two pieces?

Comment: You're trying to do too much with the OR statement.  Use two separate IF statements.